# msys2 (mingw) default library/include path configuration

Tags: mingw, msys, msys2

Is there a way that I can configure MSYS2 so that I do not have to always pass in `CPPFLAGS=-I/mingw64/include LDFLAGS=-L/mingw64/lib` to my compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to install the mingw 64 bit toolchain